# how to set MIME type of response to text/plain in REST based web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, mime

I have created a REST based web service following these instructions https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/#scratch
The main functionality of query processing is implemented in Java.

My service can accept query arguments passed through the URL. But my project specification says:
the web service must respond with a HTTP 200 OK, a response body encoded in UTF-8 and the MIME type set to ‘text/plain’.

Right now the output type seems to be json. Anyone knows how to make it ‘text/plain’?

Answer (score 0):

Add `produces = "text/plain"` to your [@RequestMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#produces%28%29) annotation.